# social icon location in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
function flx_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    // Show this on post and page only. Add filter is_home() for home page
    if(is_singular()){

        // Get current page URL
        $shortURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $shortTitle = get_the_title();`enter code here`

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$shortTitle.'&amp;url='.$shortURL.'&amp;via=flx';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$shortURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$shortURL;
        $tumblrURL = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='.$shortURL;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="flx-social">';
        $content .= '<a class="flx-link flx-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="flx-link flx-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="flx-link flx-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="flx-link flx-tumblr" href="'.$tumblrURL.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        return $content;
    }else{
        // if not post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'flx_social_sharing_buttons');
```

i use this code to display sociAl sharing buttons below my post ,

i need to add shortcode functionality so that it appears wherever i want 
how to do it pls help

Comment: Or  visit http://test.ohcampus.com/ i have set social icons there beneath red more i want these to apppear there beneath read more in every excerpt

Comment: This [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/) is giving you how to create shortcode in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You simply can do it with bellow code,

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[the_content]'); ?>
```

just pest this code where you want social icons and u can get it on those place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but hopefully you'll be able to use the following to address your challenge.

If I wanted to repurpose the function to render the social sharing buttons, I would start of by changed the first line to

```
function flx_social_sharing_buttons($content = false) {
```

The code should at this stage still, as expected, add the social sharing buttons after each post. To add it programmatically or within a post or page you can add the following line, creating a shortcode:

```
// Add the [my-social-buttons] shortcode    
add_shortcode( 'my-social-buttons', 'flx_social_sharing_buttons' );
```

> Documentation available at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
>
> Great resource for creating shortcodes and other Wordpress features:
>   http://generatewp.com

You can now use the shortcode in a post or page. To use it inside a php file, do the following

```
echo do_shortcode('[my-social-buttons]');
```

If you find that you'd rather now use your function programatically all that's left to do is to remove the original hook, if your social sharing buttons are now duplicated:

```
// Remove or comment out
// add_filter( 'the_content', 'flx_social_sharing_buttons');
```